# webpage blank on ios devices

Tags: ios, wordpress, cross-browser

I've got a simple wordpress site that's not showing up on ios devices. I've checked everything I know to check... nothing. After a long talk with the hosting IT support, we figured out that the problem was somewhere in the theme (custom made by myself, using the [underscore_s blank wordpress starter theme](http://underscores.me/)), which is developed and maintained by the wordpress creators themselves. But I haven't been able to find where the problem is coming from in the theme.

Here's' the development site: http://review.createwilmington.com

Thanks in advance for any insights... i'm out of places to check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error inside style.css file:

search for the following line and remove display:table:

```
[class*="site"]:after{content:'';display:table}
```

that working on safari for iOS device and also safari for desktop.

Comment: that did it! many *many* thanks... just before your answer i thought to check it on a desktop version of safari (should have checked this first) and had narrowed it down to a safari problem (more accurately, my code's problem in safari)... so i had just started down the road of safari trouble shooting when your answer came... perfect timing! couldn't be more grateful...