# Strange Safari cross-browser spacing issue

Tags: css, cross-browser, whitespace, safari

I've got a strange display problem in Safari that I can't seem to pinpoint. The container block spacing is ignored, making page content overlap into the footer. But here's the strange thing: when I open the developer tools (working on a PC but have a safari version installed for testing and such) the container block suddenly "registers" and the spacing is correct, as intended.

Here's the URL: http://createwilmington.com

Any ideas? Seems I'm more adapt to debugging and expecting IE issues than Safari.

Comment: I don't know about safari, but if the spacing is tied to the window size, it may be affected by opening the debugger.

Comment: Upon further inspection, it seems it's a "sticky footer" issue. I'm using [this sticky footer approach](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/), but have no clue why safari isn't recognizing it. I haven't been able to reproduce the same problem in other browser than Safari. Grateful for insights!

Comment: @SableFoste - Yes, indeed, the inspector *was* the cause of the "strangeness." Now I just need to pinpoint the CSS that's causing the spacing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing. That was the problem. A simple `"clear: both"` on the footer and "push" classes.

I had this code in my original reset,

```
[class*="site"]:after{content:'';display:table}
```

but this was breaking Safari (causing a completely white screen). As a reference for others, [here's the question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995000/webpage-blank-on-ios-devices/16995168#16995168)